# Finding conditinoal probability

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have a pratice problem I am having trouble with. I've watched tutorials and read the text book but none explain a situation like this.

An experiment consists of rolling a die twice. What is the conditional probability that the sum of the numbers showing on the two rolls is 8, given that the first roll is a 5?

What is the conditional probability that exactly four heads appear when a fair coin is flipped five times, given that the first flip was tails?

Comment: Any thoughts?  The first one at least should be intuitively clear, no?

Answer (score 0):

**Basic approach.**

1. If the first roll is a $5$, and the sum of both rolls is $8$, then
   what must the second roll be?  What is the probability of the second
   roll coming up that way.  Keep in mind that the first roll has no
   impact on the second roll.
2. If the first flip is tails, and there are four heads in all, how
   must the last four flips go?  What is the probability of them all
   coming up that way?  Again, keep in mind that that first flip has no
   impact on the succeeding four flips.

Comment: I was thinking that too but it seemed too easy. The only way the sum could be 8 is if the second roll is a 3 and that has a 1/6 chance of happening but i feel like it can't be that simple.

Comment: @griffer98: I feel it can in fact be exactly that simple. :-)  I don't see any complicating factor here.

Comment: then that would make the second answer 1/16 correct? since there are 16 possible combinations and HHHH is just one of them

Comment: @griffer98: That seems like it to me.

Answer (score 0):

The formula for the conditional probability of event $A$ given event $B$ is:
$$P(A|B) = \frac{P(A \text{ and } B)}{P(B)}.$$
Both of the experiments you describe are experiments with a finite number of equally likely outcomes. For instance, in the first experiment the sample space is the set of all ordered pairs $(x,y)$ where $x$ and $y$ are any integer between $1$ and $6$, and each such outcome has probability $\frac{1}{36}$ of occurring. Whenever your sample space consists of finitely many equally likely outcomes, the probability of an event $E$ is:
$$P(E) = \frac{\# \text{ outcomes in E}}{\# \text{ possible outcomes}}.$$
So in this special case of equally likely outcomes, we get
$$P(A \mid B) = \frac{P(A \text{ and B})}{P(B)} = \frac{\frac{\# \text{ outcomes in A and B}}{\# \text{ possible outcomes}}}{\frac{\# \text{ outcomes in B}}{\# \text{ possible outcomes}}} = \frac{\# \text{ outcomes in A and B}}{\#\text{ outcomes in B}}.$$

So to find the probability that the sum of the numbers showing on two die rolls is 8 (event $A$) given that the first roll is a $5$ (event $B$), you need to count how many ordered pairs $(x,y)$ in the sample space are in events $A$ and $B$ (i.e., they satisfy $x+y=8$ and $x=5$), and divide by how many ordered pairs $(x,y)$ in the sample space are in event $B$ (i.e., they satisfy $x=5$).

Similarly, for the second experiment, count how many sequences of length $5$ of $H,T$ satisfy that the first flip is $T$ and there are exactly four $H$. Then divide that by how many sequences satisfy that the first flip is $T$.